# convert object key with array values to query string

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to convert my object to a query string but I have an array as the values

my object looks like this

`filterChoice: {
  role: ["SW", "EW"]
  source: ["Secondary", "Tertiary"]
}`

I've gotten halfway with my conversion

```
const toQueryString = `?${Object.keys(filterChoice)
    .map(key => `${key}=${filterChoice[key].toString()}`)
    .join('&')}`
```

which outputs: `?source=Secondary,Tertiary&role=SW,EW`
but I would like this output to look like this

`?source=Secondary&source=Tertiary&role=SW&role=EW`

Could anyone help me out?

Comment: Does this make sense? Do you send that query to a server driven application or middleware? If so you can only get one role or source parameter from the query.

Comment: this is only half the query for the API, there are other variables that aren't relevant to the question

Comment: @marcel nope, that's how you pass arrays through queries (if you have to)

Comment: Well ... didn 't knew that. I have always done well with `role[]=SW&role[]=EW`. Nice to know. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @marcel yes, seen both. Finally looked it up, seems as if this is not specified at all (not even the &, = syntax), so all of this actually depends on how your backend handles it. So my previous comment doesnt make that much sense, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could flatMap the Object entries:

```
 const query = Object.entries(filterChoice)
  .flatMap(([key, value]) => [value].flat().map(v => [key, v]))
  .map(it => it.join("="))
  .join("&");
```

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect!

Comment: String should be not a "a=1&a=2" but "a[]=1&a[]=2"

Answer (score 1):

You can use URLSearchParam and iterate over the Object.keys and then each of the values

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams

```js
var filterChoice = {
  role: ["SW", "EW"],
  source: ["Secondary", "Tertiary"]
}

var URL = "https://example.com/";
var searchParams = new URLSearchParams(URL);

Object.keys(filterChoice).forEach(key => {
  filterChoice[key].forEach(val => {
    searchParams.append(key, val);
  })
})


console.log(
  searchParams.toString()
)
```